# Testing a function is not called with an argumetn

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have the following code that I want to test with Google Mock and Google Test:

```
int func1(){
  int result;
  if(condition1 && condition2){
    result = 0;
  } else {
    result = 3;
  }
  func2(result);
}
```

this a simplified version, of course.

I want to test the `if` statement. I can't change the code. I can mock `func2`.

I have to do combinatorial condition coverage, meaning I need a unit test for each of the 4 possibilities that `condition1` and `condition2`.

I understand how to do this for when `condition1` and `condition2` are both true: `EXPECT_CALL(func2(0))`.

But how should I test this either `condition1` or `condition2` are false?
Is there a `SHOULD_NOT_CALL(func2(0))`?

Let me know if my question isn't clear and what I can do to make it better
Thank you. Have a great day

Comment: You can create 4 tests, with `EXPECT_CALL(func2(0))`, .., `EXPECT_CALL(func2(3))`.

Comment: You want to know how to provoke all four possible outcomes of two conditions. For that your [mre] should provide more info on those conditions. The code you currenlty show is restricting us potential answerers to the too narrow scope which (I assume) also restricts yourself to the point that you do not see an approach. For example: The conditions might use global variables, whcih could be manipulated. They might include function calls, which could be manipulated.